# Crystal Reports Difference of group total

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a report which has two groups. Group B always has only 2 values. I want to get the difference of total values of `Item Type 01` and `Item Type 02` to the `Group B` footer (Tot type01 - tot type02).

Help me to achieve this. I tried few formulas but non of them works for me

```
                               Month01 Month2
   Group A
       Group B
          Item Type 01
              ab                 10    10
              ac                 20    30
              ad                 30    30
          **Total**              60    70

          Item Type 02
              ab                 10    20
              ac                 10    15
              ad                 20     5
          **Total**              40    30

          **Difference           20    40**
```

I want something like this

```
NumberVar sum01 := 0;
Numbervar sum02 := 0;
 GroupName ({DataTable1.IncomeType}) = Type 01
Then
 sum01 := Sum ({DataTable1.Month01}, {DataTable1.IncomeType})

if
 GroupName ({DataTable1.IncomeType}) = Type 02
Then
 sum02 := Sum ({DataTable1.Month01}, {DataTable1.IncomeType})


sum01 - sum02
```

I know this isn't correct. I used it to explain my question for you as much as possible.

Really appreciate your guidence

Comment: You can create 2 separate variable and calculate value in footer. Or you can use running total.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using arrays..

Take 2 arrays and store values for Month1 and Month2 and in group footer retrive and add those.

Create a formula @Month1Array and place in Item Type group footer after Month1 summary

```
Shared Numbervar array x;
x:=x+sum(Month1,Item GRoup);
1;
```

Create a formula @Month2Array and place in Item Type group footer after Month2 summary

```
Shared Numbervar array y;
y:=y+sum(Month2,Item GRoup);
1;
```

Now in the footer where you want to see the difference write below formula for

Create a formula @Month1

```
Shared Numbervar array x;

x[1]-x[2]
```

Create a formula @Month2

```
Shared Numbervar array y;
y[1]-y[2]
```